# How to save an array with the same spacing and origin into a SimpleITK image?

Tags: python-3.x, simpleitk

I want to write the image [that I have loaded into array] after changing the values of array into a SimpleITK Image. How can I set the spacing and origin?

[`res_file_dir` is the path to the `nii.gz` file]

```
segmentation_result=sitk.ReadImage(res_file_dir,sitk.sitkUInt8)   #segmentation_result.GetSpacing() (0.3645833432674408, 0.3645833432674408, 0.699999988079071)
seg=sitk.GetArrayFromImage(segmentation_result)  #shape (105, 242, 176)
seg[seg!=obj_label]=0

#segmentation=sitk.Image(segmentation_result.GetSize(),sitk.sitkUInt8)
 numpyOrigin = np.array(list(reversed(segmentation_result.GetOrigin())))  
 numpySpacing = np.array(list(reversed(segmentation_result.GetSpacing())))  
 segmentation = sitk.GetImageFromArray(seg, sitk.sitkVectorUInt8).SetSpacing(numpySpacing)
```

once I check the spacing of new image, it shows the following:

```
segmentation.GetSpacing()
*** AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetSpacing'
```

Comment: GetImageFromArray is supposed to return a SimpleITK Image, but here it seems to have returned a NoneType.  So something is going wrong in there.  Are you sure you want the 2nd parameter to be sitkVectorUInt8?  Your original image is not a Vector image.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your last line.  The first problem is that `segmentation` is getting set to the result of the call to `SetSpacing`, which has a return type of `void`.

The second problem is your second parameter to `sitk.GetImageFromArray`.  It is a boolean for the named parameter `isVector`.  In your case you want it to be `False`, which is the default value.

In your code, you are passing `sitk.sitkVectorUInt8`, which turns out to be an integer of value 13, to `isVector`.  So `isVector` is getting `True`, the opposite of what you really want.  With `True` you are getting a 2-d image with each pixel being a vector of length 176.

To double check, I would print out the results of the call to `sitk.GetImageFromArray` before doing the call to `SetSpacing`.

So here's what your code should be:

```
segmentation = sitk.GetImageFromArray(seg, isVector=False)
segmentation.SetSpacing(numpySpacing)
```

Note that if you want to mask out values in you image, you can do it in SimpleITK without converting to numpy and back.  Here's how you could do that:

```
# create a binary mask image of 
seg = (segmentation_result==obj_label)

# create an image with pixel values of obj_label
segmentation = seg * obj_label
```